# How to enable connector numbering on sequence diagrams in SPARX Enterprise Architect

Tags: architecture, uml, enterprise-architect

I'm using SPARX Enterprise Architect (Program Version 13.5.1351 (Build 1351)). 
I created various structural and behavioural diagrams. Recently I was asked to add some numbering and not wanting to do them manuel I wondered if there is an automatic way of doing this.

I noticed the option "Show Collaboration Numbers" on the "Connectors" tab of my sequence diagrams and saw that the option is checked, but I can't see any numbering on the diagram.

What am I missing here? Are there any other steps I have to do to get auto-numbering working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enable **Show Sequence Numbering** in **Diagrams->Sequence** section from preferences.

To Access from Ribbon : Start -> Preferences ( from Workspace group )

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks very much. I'm relatively new to EA although I used an older version years ago which I found much easier  to navigate.  This version is more powerful but I spent so much more time trying to figure out how to do things.

Comment: @JohnCambell Glad It Helped :)